# Having roles with permissions, but also add/remove permissions from individual users

Tags: php, mysqli

So what i want to do is to make a way that i can override permissions that already has been set in a role as a standard, so even when a user is a part of a role. I can go to a specific user and tell him that he's not allowed to use this specific permission, even when his role allows him to do this specific thing and vica versa!

**In my database, i have these following tabels.**

```
users:
- fk_role_id
- ...

permissions:
- perm_id
- perm_name
- perm_key

role_rights:
- fk_role_id
- fk_perm_id

user_rights:
- fk_usr_id
- fk_perm_id
- allow
```

**Breaking my code down:**

So first and off I wanted to make an array, where i could store all of my permissions. So i just could use a if(in_array()) to allow people to use certain content.

```
$g_permissions = array();
```

Here i'm joining my role_rights that contains what roles has what permissions, here i'm getting the permissions that the role with a specific ID contains.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM role_rights
            INNER JOIN permissions ON fk_perm_id = perm_id
            WHERE fk_role_id = $roleID";
$roleArray = new DBfetch($query);
```

The array that $roleArray creates:

```
role_rights - DBfetch Object
(
    [row] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fk_role_id] => 1
                    [fk_perm_id] => 1
                    [perm_id] => 1
                    [perm_name] => Admin Panel: Panel Access
                    [perm_key] => panel_access
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fk_role_id] => 1
                    [fk_perm_id] => 2
                    [perm_id] => 2
                    [perm_name] => Admin Panel: Create a user
                    [perm_key] => panel_create_user
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fk_role_id] => 1
                    [fk_perm_id] => 3
                    [perm_id] => 3
                    [perm_name] => Admin panel: Edit a user
                    [perm_key] => panel_edit_user
                )

        )

    [num_rows] => 3
)
```

Here i'm joining my user_rights that contains special rights it has an allow row that either can contain 0 or 1, if it contains 0 it means it's a permission that should be removed, and if it contains a 1 it is a permission that should be added to the array.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_rights
            INNER JOIN permissions ON fk_perm_id = perm_id
            WHERE fk_usr_id = $userID";
$userArray = new DBfetch($query);
```

The array the $userArray creates:

```
user_rights - DBfetch Object
(
    [row] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fk_usr_id] => 2
                    [fk_perm_id] => 3
                    [allow] => 0
                    [perm_id] => 3
                    [perm_name] => Admin panel: Edit a user
                    [perm_key] => panel_edit_user
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fk_usr_id] => 2
                    [fk_perm_id] => 4
                    [allow] => 1
                    [perm_id] => 4
                    [perm_name] => Admin panel: Delete a user
                    [perm_key] => panel_delete_user
                )

        )

    [num_rows] => 2
)
```

The first foreach is supposed to run everything that $roleArray has fetched, it sends me back an object, with an array i run through this array and the same with the secound one. So if the array finds a a foreign key that matches with the foreign key of the other table, it will then determain to whenever add the extra permission or remove it from the array.

```
foreach($roleArray->row as $key=>$value) {
    foreach($userArray->row as $key2=>$value2) {
        if($value["fk_perm_id"] == $value2["fk_perm_id"]) {
            if($value2["allow"] == 1) {
                $g_permissions[$value2['perm_id']] = $value2['perm_key'];
            }else{
                unset($g_permissions[$value2["perm_id"]]);
            }
        } else {
            $g_permissions[$value['perm_id']] = $value['perm_key'];
        }
    }
}
```

So what am I asking for, is a solution. So far there's no problems but two, I can't add or remove a permission from a specific user..

**All of the code:**

```
$g_permissions = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM role_rights
            INNER JOIN permissions ON fk_perm_id = perm_id
            WHERE fk_role_id = $roleID";
$roleArray = new DBfetch($query);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user_rights
            INNER JOIN permissions ON fk_perm_id = perm_id
            WHERE fk_usr_id = $userID";
$userArray = new DBfetch($query);

foreach($roleArray->row as $key=>$value) {
    foreach($userArray->row as $key2=>$value2) {
        if($value["fk_perm_id"] == $value2["fk_perm_id"]) {
            if($value2["allow"] == 1) {
                $g_permissions[$value2['perm_id']] = $value2['perm_key'];
            }else{
                unset($g_permissions[$value2["perm_id"]]);
            }
        } else {
            $g_permissions[$value['perm_id']] = $value['perm_key'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit to show an example of the content of both arrays, and your desired output

Comment: @Steve updated, everything i need comes out!

Answer (score 0):

So my solution to my problem, was to create two functions who handle the information and just add get_usr_permissions function output to my array!

```
function get_permkeys_with_user_id($userID) {

    $g_permissions = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users
            INNER JOIN role_rights ON users.fk_role_id = role_rights.fk_role_id
            INNER JOIN permissions ON permissions.perm_id = role_rights.fk_perm_id
            WHERE users.usr_id = $userID";

    $stuff = new DBfetch($query);

    foreach($stuff->row as $key=>$value) {
        $g_permissions[$value['perm_id']] = $value['perm_key'];
    }

    return $g_permissions;

}


function get_usr_permissions($userID) {

    $runQuery = new DBhandler();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_rights 
            INNER JOIN permissions ON fk_perm_id = perm_id
            WHERE user_rights.fk_usr_id = $userID";

    $perm_role = get_permkeys_with_user_id($userID);
    $perm_usr = new DBfetch($query);

    foreach($perm_usr->row as $index => $permission){
        if($permission["allow"]){
            $perm_role[$permission["perm_id"]] = $permission["perm_key"];
        }else{
            unset($perm_role[$permission["perm_id"]]);
        }
    }

    return $perm_role;
```

}